# Nest API Login/Logout using Firebase in iOS

Tags: nest-api

I have managed to create an iOS app that successfully authenticated the user and connects to the Nest structures and device settings. Using the access token, the app connects automatically to the Nest server each time the app is launched.

However, I am unable to find any documentation that explains what procedure to follow if the app needs to provide the functionality to enable log on/off for different user accounts, e.g. monitoring devices at different locations under separate user accounts from the same app.

The only way that I can change the login for a different user at this time is when I delete and re-install the app, which is not practical.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to solve this issue?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to just create a routine for getting the access token that can be reused. The login is part of the authentication process in retrieving an access token.

Once you have an access token, there isn't any open session per user account so there isn't a need to logout. Instead, just reuse the same method that got you the first access token and store as many access tokens as necessary.

Each access token is effectively a session id.